# I need to change the code of a .exe file

Tags: xml, resources, exe, reverse-engineering

I have a .exe file that ops up a black box with a basic ui. The executable is a hack for a game. When you press f1 it turns high speed on, when you press f2 it turns on high jump on, etc. So i want to change the title of the ui and i want to know how to do that. I do not have the source code.

I tried .NET reflector and it said it is not a .net assembly or something like that. Then i tried resource hacker and i didnt know what to do and there was a bunch of stuff with xml in it. So i am guessing it was made with xml

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know what language it's written in, XML is not a programming language, it's just a way to store data. What you need, is a Program **decompiler**, since a Compiler converts a source code into a executable, you need to reverse that.

Since a .Net reflector did not work, I'd suggest you to try a disassembler to get the assembly language code for a .exe file. There are various free disassembler softwares available.